# Findbugs validation in SONAR are skipping important violations

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I'm having a problem with violation in Sonar to find a basic problem in some codes that we have in my company. Below there is a test class that represents the situation that I want to clarify:

```
import entity.Cidade;

public class TesteSonar {

    public void testarSonar() {

        Cidade cidade = testarSonar2();

        cidade.getEstado();

    }

    public Cidade testarSonar2() {


        return null;
    }

}
```

In this class, we have the situation where the variable "cidade" receives the return of the method "testarSonar2()" that is null, and after that I use a action from this object. It's obvious that will throw a NullPointerException. My question is: Why findbugs didn't catch this kind of problem?

This situation points to a credibility problem in Sonar in the results that I receive from the tool. Could anyone help to understand why this is happing this way?

Thank's

Alexandre from Brazil

Comment: Did you set effort to max in the configuration of sonar for findbugs?

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a test and indeed, no error is reported.

However, please note that the problem comes from Findbugs, not from Sonar itself - as Sonar relies on external tools for bug detection. So I'd advise you to ask the question on the Findbugs' mailing list.